# Whatsapp chat link without showing mobile number in php site

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am using whatspp chat link as https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat
in my PHP web site.

But it is showing mobile number in anchor tag click url.

Is there any way to hide mobile number?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the mobile number is part of the link itself and is necessary for Whatsapp to know with whom to open the chat. You can't hide the phone number. If you're looking for more complex integrations you should have a look at the [Whatsapp Business APIs](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api/?lang=en)

Comment: yes, there is a way, convert your whatsapp app into bssnss whatsapp, and go to setting then get link there, for more info https://faq.whatsapp.com/smba/account-and-profile/about-short-links/?lang=en#:~:text=A%20short%20link%20for%20your,view%20the%20auto%2Dgenerated%20link.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Have you tried it? Has anyone succeeded in hiding phone number via the business account api?

Answer (score 0):

The phone number will in any case be visible to everyone, because as soon as you click the "Contact Us" button the messages are sent to your phone, and the number is displayed as part of the call.

If you want to hide the number only from the link itself, you can use the address shortening service as bitly

Comment: Thanks Eden. Yes actually I only want to hide number from the link itself , So could you please help me how to use "address shortening service as bitly". Please. I am using it in PHP site

Comment: You can use any address shortening service. For an example, go to https://free-url-shortener.rb.gy
And type in the input line https://wa.me/**you-phone*
Then click "shorten url".
You will receive an abbreviated address for the link you wanted .

If my answer helped you, please mark the question as a button. Click the small V next to the answer I provided